# ImportError: cannot import name 'ParamSpec' from 'typing_extensions' when using Django websockets with channels and twisted libraries

Tags: python, django, websocket, twisted, django-channels

We did not update any lib or new lib added. During deployment of Django web application, got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py", line 118, in django_setup
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/channels/apps.py", line 4, in <module>
    import daphne.server
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/daphne/server.py", line 5, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import asyncioreactor  # isort:skip
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/asyncioreactor.py", line 19, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.posixbase import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 16, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import error, tcp, udp
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 99, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import abstract, address, base, error, fdesc, main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 34, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import abstract, defer, error, fdesc, main, threads
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 42, in <module>
    from typing_extensions import Literal, ParamSpec, Protocol
ImportError: cannot import name 'ParamSpec' from 'typing_extensions' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/typing_extensions.py)
```

This seems to be involving typing_extensions from Python package.

Comment: You probably did upgrade some library (Twisted, I would guess) and likely need to also upgrade typing_extensions to a version that includes ParamSpec.

Answer (score 1):

So, it turned out that I did not update any library. But, in `requirements.txt`,  only `channels` library specific version was mentioned. So during server deployment the version of `channels` stayed the same.

Meanwhile [twisted](https://pypi.org/project/Twisted/#history) library is a 3rd level dependency and not directly mentioned in my `requirements.txt`. So `twisted` library got updated on its own without a warning as it's latest version 22.10.0 released.

During deployment it led to above error straight away making us wonder who updated it.

To resolve this issue, we tried using the updated the version of `twisted` but it led to another error even version 4.4.0 and 4.0.0

In the end, we took all the libs using `pip freeze` from stable running Docker container (virtual env, in your case maybe) and added all the required dependencies in the `requirements.txt`. This will keep away the unexpected library upgraded happening silently in the background.

Comment: +1, had the same problem but with celery+sqs, after some ci/cd library got updated because I didn't pin versions inside requirements.txt.